# How to continue application when its getting error 404 or timeout

Tags: c#, winforms

Is there any way to make code still continue even if its getting timeout or 404 error....
HttpWebRequest and HttpWebResponse case:

here my code:

```
string argumentTest = textBox1.text.Trim(); 

string[] lines = textBox1.Text.Split(new string[] { "\r\n", "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
string newLine = ((char)13).ToString() + ((char)10).ToString();

 foreach (string vr in lines)
{
  string sourceCode = getSourceCode(vr);
  if (sourceCode != null)
  {
    //if this code is up
  } else {
    //if this code is down
  }

}

public static string getSourceCode(string url)
        {
            HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            req.ContentType = "text/html; charset=ISO-8859-15";
            //ERROR in here 404 or timeout
            HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream()); 
            string sourceCode = sr.ReadToEnd();
            sr.Close();
            resp.Close();
            return sourceCode;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle the exception using [try-catch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yd65esw%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) block, If you have to clean up any resources allocated you can use [finally](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zwc8s4fz%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) block which will be exectuted in both cases.

```
public static string getSourceCode(string url)
{
       string sourceCode = string.Empty;
       try
       { 
        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        req.ContentType = "text/html; charset=ISO-8859-15";
        //ERROR in here 404 or timeout
        HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream()); 
        sourceCode = sr.ReadToEnd();
        sr.Close();
        resp.Close();

      }
      catch(Exception ex){}
      return sourceCode;
}
```

Comment: getting error like this
`Error 1 'testingurl.Form1.getSourceCode(string)': not all code paths return a value`

Comment: We need to ensure that our method returns a string due to return type, we can take return statement out of try catch block as in case of exception compiler could skip it. Check my updated code.

Comment: Wow, its worked.. But I need change my code to checking string 

`if (sourceCode != string.Empty))`